# Longest Palindromic Substring (C++ Help)

Tags: c++

I had trouble printing my output for the longest palindromic substring and have not yet figured out. My code prints out a palindrome if the input is a palindromic string, but is not able to print out the palindromic substring. There is something wrong with the else function of this code and wanted to know where the bug is:

```
string longestSubstring(string str){

    int size = str.size();
    string newStr = "";

    if(str[0] == str[size - 1]){
        for(int i = size - 1;i >= 0;i--){
            newStr += str[i];
        }
        if(str == newStr){
            return newStr;
        }
    }

    else{
        for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++){
            for(int k = size - 1; k > 0; k--){
                if(str[j] == str[k] && k != j){
                    for(int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--){
                        newStr += str[i];
                    }
                }
                k = 0;
                j = size;
            }
        }
    }
    return newStr;
}

int main() {
    string palindromeStr;

    cout << longestSubstring(palindromeStr);  
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for whoever is able to provide assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in the innermost loop.

```
for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++){
    for(int k = size - 1; k > 0; k--){
        if(str[j] == str[k] && k != j){
            for(int i = size - 1;i > 0;i--){
                newStr += str[i];
            }
        }
        k = 0;
        j = size;
    }
}
```

I think that you're trying to compare every character of the substring with the character on the other side. This approach is correct, and would work if implemented correctly.

However, the loop only compares the characters on the leftmost and rightmost end of the string (str[k] and str[j]), which means it almost always leaves out the majority of the characters in the string.

Here's my code, which implements the approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(string str){
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.size()/2; ++i){
        if(str[i] != str[str.size()-1-i]){return false;}
    }
    return true;
}

string longestSubstring(string str){
    int len = str.size();
    for(int size = len; size >= 1; --size){ // test every possible size
        for(int start = 0; start < len-size; ++start){
            if(isPalindrome(str.substr(start, size))){
                return str.substr(start, size);
            }
        }
    }

    return "";
}

int main() {
    string palindromeStr;
    cin >> palindromeStr;

    cout << longestSubstring(palindromeStr);  
    return 0;
}
```